# How to append input type text value to a href laravel?

Tags: laravel-5.4

I had a link which will get the value of input(text) if not empty and append it to href value. Is there a way to accomplish it?. Heres my code. Thanks in advance.

```
<a id= "lnk_audio_devices" href="{{route('search.products', ['category' => 'audio_devices',
          @if(txt_product.value != '')
            'products' => txt_product.value
          @endif
           ])}}" >Audio Devices</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you might want to try a workaround with a form, that is the usual way things like these are done, leading to an url like this `foobar.com/foo/bar?yourinput=whatyoutyped`. Instead of the button being a link, it nom submits the form.

If you want to keep your laravel routing the same. You will need javascript to append the text value to the link when the button is clicked.

```js
function navigate(link, inputid){
  var url = link.href + "/" + document.getElementById(inputid).value;
  //window.location.href = url; //navigates to the given url, disabled for demo
  alert(url);
}
```

```html
<a href="" onClick="navigate(this,'myText')">click me</a>
<input type="text" id="myText">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe because i wanted to use  'route' in my href thats why i cant get it right. I try your code but the problem is it always redirecting mo to the same link not in the desired url. I think its because of href="". And the second is if there parameter in url , it always getting it.. So i try to modify your code.

Comment: Here's my new code ..function navigate(category ){
  var text_search = document.getElementById('search').value.trim();
  text_search = (text_search == '') ? '' : '&product=' + text_search;
  category = '?category=' + category;
  var url = window.location.origin + '/' + category + text_search;
  window.location.href = url;
}